# Cannot parse Date into different format

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, date-format

I have date in String as  **Wed Sep 30 18:37:04 IST 2015**
I want to convert it into **09-30-2015** format.

I have tried

```
var dateString = "Wed Sep 30 18:37:04 IST 2015";
var d = new Date(dateString);
```

But it is giving invalid date.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you don't even need to use the `Date` constructor. You can manipulate the string like this:

```js
var input = "Wed Sep 30 18:37:04 IST 2015";
var splits = input.split(" ");
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var finalDate = (months.indexOf(splits[1]) + 1) + "-" + splits[2] + "-" + splits[5].slice(-2);

alert(finalDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function for formatting date in jQuery. Either you have to use jquery plugins or do it manually. For JQuery plugin you can use this [Link](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)

For manual use below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var d = new Date(); 
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    alert(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
});
```